# How do I reorder ggplot2::facet_wrap facets by a specific key?

Tags: r

From my dataset, I have created multiple facets. now the facets actually ordered by the type of chrl.
I want to reorder the facets by the latitude. For example, the facets with the lowest latitude value will come up first, then next, etc.

### My table:

### Location | coralType | Longitude | Latitude | Year | value |

Link to dataset -- https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-z-iKk7_IvGKjhEblcPDlTA2II1GBFF4

My current facets screenshot [Facets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Co4l.png)

My current code snippets are:

```
require(ggplot2)
coralData<-read.csv("datasets.csv")
coralData$location<-as.factor(coralData$location)
coralData$value<-as.numeric(sub("%","",coralData$value))
coralData$year<-as.factor(coralData$year)
coralData$coralType<-as.factor(coralData$coralType)
ggplot(coralData, aes(year, value))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(coralType~location)+
  geom_smooth(aes(group = 1),
              method = "lm",
              color = "black",
              se = FALSE)
```

Comment: Could you provide a minimal, reproducible example of the data? One idea is using `fct_reorder` to use latitude to reorder site. You should also look at using `facet_grid` instead of `facet_wrap` for this example

Comment: Aurthur, if you want us to test your code with your data, are you honestly expecting us to transcribe from an image to something usable? Instead of images, please include usable data, preferably from `data.frame(...)` (built manually) or `dput(x)` where `x` is a sufficiently-representative sample of your data.

Comment: Regardless, though, almost every time I see questions involving `ggplot2` and *"ordering facets"* (or colors or shapes or something), the answer almost always includes `factor`s. `ggplot2` will honor the order of `levels=` in your factors, so if you set the ordinality of your data, it will fall into place.

Comment: My Apologies, I will edit and post the actual data and code

Comment: @csgroen I have edited the post and shared the data

Answer (score 0):

You should use `dput()` to allow us to reproduce your data - nobody is going to download data from a google drive link to help.

as @r2evans said, you can reorder most aspects of a ggplot figure using the factor, including facets:

From mtcars, say we want to split `wt~mpg` by different levels in cyl, but re-order the facets in descending order of cyl. Use the factor function and levels argument accordingly:

```
mtcars$cyl = factor(mtcars$cyl, levels=rev(unique(sort(mtcars$cyl))))
mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(~cyl)
```

[image]